# Printing issue with Java.awt.print.PrinterJob

Tags: java, printing, awt

Using this PrinterJob i would like to print the pdf file where we dont want user to select the format of printing and filename. I mean that the file name and path will be given from code as that file is to be reused. Currently my code is

```
PrinterJob pJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
Paper paper = new Paper();

PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
pageFormat.setPaper(paper);
printJob.setPrintable(this, pageFormat);

if (printJob.printDialog() == false)
{
    return false;
}

try
{
    preparePrintJob(); // This method will create all header,detail and footer
    printJob.print();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

This is just a sample code where there is no issue in printing but my requirement is to not to show dialog for which i will remove the printJob.printDialog() line and then how can i set the filepath and filename? Also the format of file should be pdf as the saved file is to be fetched and reused

Answer (score 0):

Consult the [PrinterJob API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html#setJobName(java.lang.String)) to find the `setJobName` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use method print(PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes). So You can manually set all required attributes.

Comment: can you please provide a sample how to set an attributes as i didnt find anywhere setting filename and all on google